# How to remove sequences from longitudal data based on a given condition?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a vector of consecutive states (you can only go from 3 to 4, from 4 to 5 etc., and there's no way back):

```
cons_states <- c(3,4,5,6)
```

Simultenously I have data:

```
from to  status id
2    3   1      1
2    4   0      2
2    5   0      3
2    6   0      4
2    8   0      5
2    16  0      6
3    4   0      7
3    8   0      8
3    16  1      9
16   3   0      10
16   4   0      11
16   5   0      12
16   6   0      13
16   8   1      14
8    3   0      15
8    4   1      16
8    5   0      17
8    6   0      18
```

I have two assumptions that I would like my data to perform:

if state was visited there's no way back, for example once state 3 was visited (to=3 & status=1) there shouldn't be anymore possibility to move to state 3 from the next states (there shouldn't be anymore to=3):

```
from to  status id
2    3   1      1
2    4   0      2
2    5   0      3
2    6   0      4
2    8   0      5
2    16  0      6
3    4   0      7
3    8   0      8
3    16  1      9
16   4   0      11
16   5   0      12
16   6   0      13
16   8   1      14
8    4   1      16
8    5   0      17
8    6   0      18
```

I managed to do it with (it's ugly I realize it, but it works):

```
  ind <- data[which(data$status == 1),]
  
  res <- NULL
  for (j in 1:nrow(ind)){
    ind_to <- unlist(ind [j,c("to")])
    ind_id <- unlist(ind [j,c("id")])
    id_remove <- data[which(data$to == ind_to & data$id> ind_id ),"seq"]
    if(length(id_remove) == 0) next
    res <- rbind(id_remove, res)
  }
```

Which gives me a vector of IDs to remove from my data that fulfills my first assumption.

Also I would like to meet an assumption that if we going to state that belongs to vector cons_states we can go only to the consecutive one yet no visited. As we can see if the state number in "from" belongs to cons_states vector - the problem doesn't exist. Otherwise there's a possibility to move to other states only than the consecutive.

My desired output would be:

```
from to  status id
2    3   1      1
2    8   0      5
2    16  0      6
3    4   0      7
3    8   0      8
3    16  1      9
16   4   0      11
16   8   1      14
8    4   1      16
```

I spent a lot of time trying to figure it out but I'm stucking on writing complicated loops that doesn't work. Is there any not super complicated way to do it?

Comment: I think I follow the first assumption, but not the second. Could you explain further why rows are removed for the second assumption? Perhaps explain for several cases more clearly why the rows remained or were removed.

Comment: Sure, I'll update my post afternoon. Thank you for a response.

Comment: Happy to review again after you update your post.

Comment: I still did not update it, i'm sorry. I have been really busy working on another thing. I'll try to do it asap.